# Java - class cast exception from wrong type

Tags: java, spring, classcastexception

Running Java 1.8 (And Spring 4.0, which is responsible for some of this wiring), I have the following code:

```
public void doStuff(String color, Collection<String> ids)  {
  for (String id : ids) {
```

On that last line, I get the exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

the toString of the collection returns: [521356090]

It is being passed to this method from this code:

```
doStuff("green", this.regionToIds.get(3L))
```

Why am I getting this exception? Why is the Set and then collection have an object that my foreach loop has a problem with?

This class is wired in as a resource:

```
private Map<Long, Set<String>> regionToIds;

@Resource(name = Config.REGION_TO_IDS)
public void setRegionToIds(
    final Map<Long, Set<String>> regionToIds) {
    this.regionToIds = regionToIds;
}
```

The config file looks like this:

```
@Bean(name = REGION_TO_IDS)
public Map<Long, Set<String>> getRegionToIds() { .. }
```

I actually just noticed that I have two beans defined in my Config file, and the value being returned is the value of the other bean, which is a `Map<Long, List<Long>>`. However, it has an entirely different bean name so I don't understand why that resource is pulling in the wrong bean.

Comment: The error seems pretty self-explanatory: `this.setOfStringsByLong.get(3L)` is either 1) failing to return a Collection<String>, and/or 2) failing to convert a Long element into a String element.  Right?

Comment: Can you give us some more details about setOfStringsByLong?  What's the return type on that get?  Can you share the source/API for setOfStringsByLong?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: @HotLicks Thanks for the info. The desired behavior is to not throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

This was caused by using the same bean name for both of the beans I defined in my config file. I originally missed this because they were two different enums. Interestingly, spring manages to pass along a `Map<Long,List<Long>>` as a `Map<Long,List<String>>` until I try to treat that List as a List, where it finally has a runtime exception.